# how to access post parameters in php?

Tags: extjs, yii, extjs4

I am working in Extjs4 plus yii framework and using MVC structure. I am going to send data from extjs4 to yii framework. I am using post method to send data to server side, but I am not yet succeed to display data in yii framework. When I am using get() method the data  accessed to yii framework side easily. Actually I dont want to display data in url so thats why I am using post() method in extjs4.

Here is my some code:

1. Model file:

   ```
   Ext.define('Bal.model.sn.UserModel', {
       extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
       //idproperty:'userId',//fields property first position pk. 
       fields: ['userId', 'firstName', 'middleName', 'lastName', 'languageId', 'primaryEmail', 'birthDate', 'password', 'securityQuestionId', 'securityQuestionAnswer', 'isMale', 'creationTime', 'ipAddress', 'confirmationCode', 'userStatusId', ]
   });
   ```
2. Store file:

   ```
   Ext.define('Bal.store.sn.UserStore', {
       extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
       model: 'Bal.model.sn.UserModel',
       //autoLoad: true,

       proxy: {
           type: 'ajax',
           api: {
               read: 'http://localhost/balaee/Balaee/index.php/SocialNetworking/user/AuthenticateLogin',
               create: 'http://localhost/balaee/Balaee/index.php/SocialNetworking/user/AuthenticateLogin',
               //update: ,
               //destroy: ,
           }, //End of api
           extraParams: {
               hello: 'Inside store',
           },
           actionMethods: {
               create: 'POST',
               read: 'POST',
               update: 'POST',
               destroy: 'POST'
           },
           reader: {
               type: 'json',
               //root: ,
               //successProperty: ,
           }, //End of reader
           writer: {
               type: 'json',
               root: 'records',
           }, //End of writer
       } //End of proxy

   }); //End of store
   ```
3. My controller file some code:

   ```
   var obj = this.getStore('sn.UserStore');
   obj.load({
       params: {
           hello: 'jitu'
       }
   });
   ```
4. And here is my yii framework controller file code:

   ```
   $postData = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
   $clientData = $postData['records'];

   echo $_POST['hello'];
   ```

How can I display this hello parameter in yii framework? Please give some suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I use something like this. if $_POST['PostDataName'] is empty getPost($name) returns NULL

```
public function actionFoo()
{
   $data = Yii::app()->request->getPost('PostDataName');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What error you are getting. Like 400, 404, 500 etc. Also do you have CSRF enabled in your YII app. If not then something like this should do.

```
public function actioTest()
{
    $post = $_POST['hello'];
}
```

If CSRF is enabled then you have to pass CSRF value with the request as well.

Comment: May I know why this was down voted. Did you even check YII documentation before down voting this post.